# See chart in R Shell

Tags: r, shell, graph, plot

I have a simple **R** script doing:

```
 jpeg(myplot.jpg) 
 x<-seq(1,20,0.1)
 y<-sin(x)
 plot(x,y)
 dev.off()
```

After execution it makes a myplot.jpg file in /root/work/ but renders gibberish information and does not plot a legible graph.

Also how can I view the graph in **R** shell itself?

Answer (score 3):

The first argument to `jpeg` should be a character string, so I wouldn't expect your code to work unless `myplot.jpg` contained a character string.  This works fine for me:

```
jpeg("myplot.jpg") 
x<-seq(1,20,0.1)
y<-sin(x)
plot(x,y)
dev.off()
```

Whether you can view the graph in the "shell" depends on the R console you're using.  If you're running R from bash, sh, etc, the answer is "no, you can't view a plot directly"... actually it wouldn't surprise me if there was a package that allowed you to create text-plots, but I don't think that's what you want.

Comment: no it's not about the double quotes..my image file is still showing gibbersih text instead of image

Comment: @user3548020: What program are you using to view the image file?

Comment: @user3548020 "linux default viewer" is not a program, and is too vague a description. Which distribution of linux? What is the actual name of the program being run?

Comment: It was WinSCP's Internal Text Editor..I opened it with windows photo viewer and correct image was rendered.Thanks for constant replies..Your help is appreciated

Comment: @user3548020 What do you expect an image file to look like in a text editor? Last time I checked, R doesn't have an ascii art device.

Comment: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/18352/is-there-a-command-line-program-that-can-output-ascii-art-as-an-image